# Recursive Solution to Free Memory in C

Tags: c, algorithm, shell, recursion, memory

I am working on building a shell and have this function that frees memory of the programs in the command line. I am interested in trying to create a recursive solution as I am trying to better understand recursion.

The program struct in the header file looks like this and is implemented as a linked list so it can support pipes.

```
// The program to be executed
typedef struct prog {
  arglist_t args; // Arguments, including the program name
  redirection_t redirection; // Optional redirections
  struct prog *prev; // The prev program in the pipeline, if any; NULL otherwise
} prog_t;
```

This is the iterative free memory function implementation:

```
void free_memory(prog_t *exe) {
  prog_t *tmp;

  while(exe != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < exe->args.size; i++) {
       if(exe->args.args[i]) free(exe->args.args[i]);
    }
    free(exe->args.args);
    if (exe->redirection.in) free(exe->redirection.in);
    if (exe->redirection.out1) free(exe->redirection.out1);
    if (exe->redirection.out2) free(exe->redirection.out2);

    if(exe->redirection.in != NULL) {
      free(exe->redirection.in);
    }

    if(exe->redirection.out1 != NULL) {
      free(exe->redirection.out1);
    }

    if(exe->redirection.out2 != NULL) {
      free(exe->redirection.out2);
    }
    tmp = exe;
    exe = exe->prev;
    free(tmp);
    } 
}
```

How would I go about developing a recursive solution?

Comment: What makes you think a recursive solution would be more efficient? Your iterative solution is clear, concise, and probably as efficient as it gets. A recursive solution will add function call overhead for no gain.

Comment: Why complicate something so simple with recursion? There's nothing to gain from it, surely not speed or efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am just curious as to how a recursive solution would be implemented

Comment: Every loop `for (NODE *p = head; p; p = p->next) foo(p);` can be re-implemented as a recursive function `void loop(NODE *p) { if (!p) return; foo(p); loop(p->next); }`. As others have said, there's no sense in doing this. In the best case, the compiler will turn it back to iteration in the machine code it generates.

Comment: The downside with recursion and lists is potential for stack exhaustion for a large list. With a 4M stack on Linux, you get roughly 100K recursive calls before StackOverflow. On windows with a 1M stack, much less. For most lists that isn't an issue, but for any large collection (or if you just don't know how many nodes you may have), an iterative solution is usually the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recursion, you call instead of looping.  For your case, change the `while` into an `if` and change the last three lines of the while/if body to

```
free_memory(exe->prev);
free(exe);
```

or to make it more efficient (tail recursive):

```
tmp = exe->prev;
free(exe);
free_memory(tmp);
```

the tail recursive version will probably generate identical code to your while loop.